# Error Async Task doInBackground() & JSoup

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I've tried to connect Async with JSoup.
I want to get title from the URL, but catch an exception.
But I don't understand why

My LogCat is:

```
    12-14 23:54:19.612: I/Process(568): Sending signal. PID: 568 SIG: 9
12-14 23:54:55.141: D/gralloc_goldfish(632): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-14 23:55:01.051: I/dalvikvm(632): Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.example.myexample.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground
12-14 23:55:01.081: W/dalvikvm(632): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3465: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;.connect (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection;
12-14 23:55:01.081: D/dalvikvm(632): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
12-14 23:55:03.111: W/dalvikvm(632): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.example.myexample.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:50)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.example.myexample.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-14 23:55:03.181: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  ... 5 more
```

As I know I have a mistake with a section `doInBackground`.
When I change params[0] to params I have an error too

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MyTask mt;
  TextView tvInfo;
  String URL="http://www.yandex.ru/";
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
  }

  public void onclick(View v) {
    mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute(URL);
  }

  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      Document doc;
      String title=null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      tvInfo.setText("Please wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      try {
       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
       doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
       String title = doc.title();
       Log.d("AsyncTask doInBackground","URL: " + params[0]);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return title;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      tvInfo.setText(title);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure the proper version of jsoup is exported in your app

Comment: I use the final version of JSOUP (1.7.1)

Answer (score 1):

Using params as an array, `params[0]   params[1] ...` is correct.

Can you add a general exception catch so see more specifics about the JSoup connection error?

Also, log the value of params[0] to make sure that it is a valid URL:

```
Log.d("AsyncTask doInBackground","URL: " + params[0]);
```

Although your project would not compile without them, make sure you are importing the correct Java JSoup libraries. Your error says it cannot find the static method `connection`.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

Comment: relevance to ths question ? this kind of error would be detected at compile time.

Comment: Good point. let me update my answer. Why would the compiler find the method during compilation but then it be absent at runtime? `Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.example.example.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground`

Comment: I don't know why compilation doesn't except at this row.The LogCat underlined as green light

Comment: fatal exception starts only with AsyncTask doInBackground ((

Comment: I did all that @jamisOn wrote, bit it didn.t help. What else it was?

Comment: If the JSoup connection method compiles, but then crashes, then it has to be either the value you're passing to it (the URL) or the actual function connection in the JSoup library. Can you redownload the JSoup library? Did you verify the URL coming from params[0] is correct?

Comment: All evening I tried to repair my app, but it was unsuccessful.
I redownload JSoup, add log,but unfortunately it doesn.t help
I update Log Cat above

Comment: As you can see I don't can see the log, but I added it (I update code above too)